# Camel ExchangeCompletedEvent vs. RoutePolicy.onExchangeDone

Tags: apache-camel

My camel route is configured like this (pseudocode)

```
from(direct:in).to(jdbc:db).split().body().streaming().parallelProcessing()
.process(doSomething).process(createDBquery).out(jdbc:db)
```

The jdbc endpoint is configured to put out `JdbcOutputType.StreamList`. The route is triggered by sending a select query into direct:in. Each line from db is handled in `doSomething`. It creates a special result object that is converted into a query to write the result into db.

My main problem is how to detect if the complete result from db was handled- **I want to know when it is finished**.

I tried to use an EventNotifier and filtered on `ExchangeCompletedEvent`. But this event seems to be raised for every result written into db. Now i am considering the use of `RoutePolicy` / overriding "onExchangeDone" but would this change anything?

What are the exact semantics of both especially for routes that create new exchanges (e.g. by split) on their way?
Is their a clean way to detect when my route is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I 've got an [answer from Claus itself in camel user group](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-ExchangeCompletedEvent-vs-RoutePolicy-onExchangeDone-tp5772140p5772143.html).
Using RoutePolicy is better here because it only calls onExchangeDone on the original Exchange.
By using the event we have to filter out the exchanges from split. This could be done by checking for presence of property 'Exchange.CORRELATION_ID'.

Other viable solutions would be the use of '.onCompletion()' or synchronization which works this way:

```
from("direct:confirm")
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getUnitOfWork()
              .addSynchronization(new FileRollback());
}
})
```